# embedding a web page in iFrame problem

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I embedded a web page in an iFrame like this:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="http://www.domain.com" width="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

Edit: The problem i am having is that the web page javascript is using the top property to find objects but now it is embedded in the iframe, is there a way to over ride this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to send data from the iFrame to the parent? If so, the error happens because Cross Site Communication is usually blocked to avoid XSS attacks. But you can keep your iframe, and use JavaScript and the window.postMessage(); function to share data.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage